# proving logical inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this problem: Write the following premises and the conclusion as logical statements and prove the conclusion correct: (use the symbols in brackets.)

If the train is late, I will spend the night in Pennsylvania. If I miss my train I will spend the night in Manhattan. Either my train is not late, or I did not miss my train from Fordham, but not both. Therefore either I will spend the night in Pennsylvania, or I will spend the night in Fordham.(L, P, M, F)

The problem's been bugging me for hours and I don't know where to start.

I just know that:

L ⇒ P

M ⇒ F

~P ⊕ ~F

Therefore: P ∨ F

How do I prove this? I also don't get the xor in the premise. any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot spend the night in both places, you should use P ⊕ F as the result; so:

1. ~P ⊕ ~F goes: [~P][~~F] ∨ [~~P][~F]
2. By double complement: [~P][F] ∨ [P][~F]
3. By commutativity and def'n of XOR: P ⊕ F